# Unable to set property 'selected' using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a series of CheckBox elements whose Id matches the values of  tags within the same form.

My intention is that, when I Check a checkbox, the  tag gets selected.

When I uncheck the checkbox, the  tag gets deselected.

This implementation is for a select tag with multi-select.

> JS code

```
    function setPermissions(val) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(String(val));

    if (checkBox.checked) {
        $("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").prop("selected", false);
    }
    else {
        console.log("!checked", val);
        $("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").prop('selected', true);
        //$("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
}
```

> Checkbox

```
   @foreach (var p in ViewBag.Permissions)
    {
        <li class="form-control">
            <input class="isCheckbox" style="vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" value="@p.id" id="@p.id" onclick="setPermissions(@p.id)">
            <label for="@p.id">
                @p.name
            </label>
        </li>
    }
```

> Select

```
<select id="permissions">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Permissions)
{
    <option value="@item.id"></option>
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion - you can simplify your `setPermissions` with replacing `if...else` code with `$("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").prop("selected", checkBox.checked);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` instead of `onclick`

Comment: Sadly it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want it to do, but this might solve your problems

```
function setPermissions(obj) {
  $("#permissions option[value=" + obj.value + "]").prop('selected', obj.checked);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function setPermissions(obj) {
  $("#permissions option[value=" + obj.value + "]").prop('selected', obj.checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="form-control">
    <input class="isCheckbox" style="vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" value="test1" id="test1" onclick="setPermissions(this)">
    <label for="test1">
                test1
            </label>
  </li>
  <li class="form-control">
    <input class="isCheckbox" style="vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" value="test2" id="test2" onclick="setPermissions(this)">
    <label for="test2">
                test2
            </label>
  </li>
  <li class="form-control">
    <input class="isCheckbox" style="vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox" value="test3" id="test3" onclick="setPermissions(this)">
    <label for="test3">
                test3
            </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<select id="permissions" multiple>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have several checkboxes. Whenever one is checked, the corresponding <option> tag should toggle its selected value.

Comment: Your <select> does not have the multiple tag so you can't select multiple

Comment: @ChampR try the demo now

Answer (score 0):

When `checkBox.checked` is true,you should use `prop('selected', true)`,and when it is false,use `prop('selected', false)`.That's why your js does not work.

```
function setPermissions(val) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(String(val));

    if (checkBox.checked) {
        $("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").prop("selected", true);
    }
    else {
        console.log("!checked", val);
        $("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").prop('selected', false);
        //$("#permissions option[value=" + val + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
}
```